# IOS View controller communicate

Tags: ios

Hi I have a view controller A that deal with view A, and a view controller B for view B. Now to go to view B when user click a button in view A?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UINavigationController , the NavigationController's rootViewController is view A .  When the user clicks the button at view A, push View controller B onto the NavigationController. use this method: pushViewController:

good luck with you!

Answer (score 0):

Push View Controller A onto a UINavigationController to begin with.  When the user clicks on the button in view A, push View Controller B onto the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBAction method for the button, initialize your view B, and push it onto the view stack.

This is very well documented in the documentation. You should check it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard this becomes much much easier.  Just select the scene for View A in the Storyboard view, then on the Menu bar, Click Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller.  This will add the Nav Controller automagically and make View A the Root View Controller.  Then it is just a matter of wiring up a Segue from View A to View B.